# Camunda rest engine URL in Springboot starter

Tags: spring-boot, camunda

I created multiple Camunda instances using spring boot starter, each one with different application path and different process engine name, then exported each one as a war and deployed them on external tomcat server.

The web applications are working fine, but I can't access the REST APIs.

I configured the instances to:

- have different engine names
- have different admin users
- connect to different database schemas
- have different application paths.

All in `application.yml` file, using the following properties: `spring.datasource`, `url`, `jdbc`, `oracle`, `username`, `password`, `driver-class-name`, `camunda.bpm`, `admin-user`, `id`, `password`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `process-engine-name`, `spring.jersey.application-path`.

I am accessing the webapps using this link `http://host:port/application-path/camunda/app/welcome/engine-name/#!/welcome`

How could I access the engine-rest?

I tried:

- `http://host:port/application-path/engine-rest`
- `http://host:port/engine-rest`
- `http://host:port/application-path/engine-rest/engine/enine-name`

and all of them are not working. Any thoughts on how to access the api?

Answer (score 1):

The Camunda rest-api uses Jersey and the application-path engine-rest.
So I think your different applications are clashing here.

Try to set a different

```
spring.jersey.application-path
```

config in the application.properties for each web application.

Comment: as I mentioned in the question, I did set `spring.jersey.application-path`   property but still cannot access the REST engine, I getting 404.

I don't know if doing this step right. could you please provide me an example , and how engine-rest could be accessed then.

Comment: the path is not going to be engine-rest anymore. You need to use the value you set in the property. Also you wrote about application paths, but it is not clear if you are referring to the web application paths or the jersey setting. Please add your exact application.properties to the post if this does not help already.